# ClipboardJS with React, using document.getElementById()

Tags: dom, reactjs, clipboard.js, virtual-dom

Originally, I had it working fine.

Then I did this and now I can't get it to work

**ClipboardField.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {

  return(
    <div id="clip" data-clipboard-text={props.code} onClick={props.onClick}>
      <p> Copy to clipboard.</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Field.js**

```
class DashWizardTwoCore extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    const btns = document.getElementById('clip');
    const clipboard = new Clipboard(btns);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }


  render(){

    const someCode = "const foo = 1"

    return (
      <div>
        <ClipboardField code={this.someCode} /> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you take the code out of **ClipboardField** and into **Field** it works. It's mostly, how do I use document.getElementById() in my parent component to find something in my child?

Their examples:

https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/blob/master/demo/constructor-selector.html#L18

https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/blob/master/demo/constructor-node.html#L16-L17

https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/blob/master/demo/constructor-nodelist.html#L18-L19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine you just have a few issues:

- you are binding `clipboard.on` in `componentDidUpdate` which won't trigger here since you are not really changing anything (in the `ClipboardField` component) that triggers this event.
- You are passing `{this.someCode}` in the `code` prop which would be undefined should just be `{someCode}`

So it's just a matter of moving your `clipboard.on` to the `componentDidMount` right after the `new Clipboard` and use `code={someCode}`

https://jsfiddle.net/yy8cybLq/

--

In React whenever you want to access the actual dom element of your component we use what react calls as refs, I would suggest you do this rather than using `getElementById` as this is the "best practice".

However stateless components (like your `ClipboardField` component above) can't have refs so you just need to change it to be a normal component.

Here's a fiddle with your code but using refs instead: https://jsfiddle.net/e5wqk2a2/

I tried including links to the react docs for stateless components and refs but apparently don't have enough "rep" to post more than 2 links, anyways quick google search should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted your code and created a simple integration of `clipboard.js` with React.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/ehrbvkc1/13/ . Check it out.